# how to send notification for specific group when new employee created in odoo v10?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

i have never been working on odoo email template or notification,
i need to know how to notify spacific Group of user when new employee is created 
if there is any example it will be appreciated i'am trying to do that on odoo10

Answer (score 1):

You should create a module and inherit the model "hr.employee".

And then override the function "create" on your module like this:

> Option 1 This way notify each user one by one

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
   all_users = self.env['res.users'].search([('active', '=', True)])
   my_users_group = all_users.filtered(lambda user: user.has_group('my.group.name'))
   for i in range(0, len(my_users_group)):
       item = my_users_group[i]
       item.message_post("New employee created")
   record = super(MyHrModuleName, self).create(values)
   return record
```

Another way of how to do it:

> Option 2 This way notify all your users in your group at the same time.

Go to the "Discuss" application and create a private channel and auto subscribe your users.

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    my_private_channel = self.env['mail.channel'].search([('name', 'ilike', "My-Private-Channel")])
    my_private_channel.message_post("New employee has been created")
    record = super(MyHrModuleName, self).creates(values)
    return record
```

Any two options that you choose is ok...
Any concern about it, let me know.

I recommend you to read the whole Odoo Documentation that is very user friendly about how to create and inherit a new module.

> https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/module.html

Comment: i get this error when create 
TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'

Comment: i wrote it like that and it's work well , @norbertoonline


    `@api.model
    def create(self, values):
        all_users = self.env['res.users'].search([('active', '=', True)])
        my_users_group = all_users.filtered(lambda user: user.has_group('base.group_user'))
        for i in range(0, len(my_users_group)):
            item = my_users_group[i]
            item.message_post(body='New employee created', message_type='notification')
            print ('i'am IN')
        return super(hr_employee, self).create(values)`

Comment: but actually i don't know where this notification is appears , i create the employee without any error, and when i go to setting messages i found the notification , but ineed to know how other users will recive this notification ??

Comment: @MohamedFouad I already modified the function because I forget to make the return... And take this example of where to do things on "creation"... Remember read the doc. The others employees will receive the message in the same way, because that function will send a message to each one of your employees you could try to create a private channel and make an auto subscription of your group and modify the function to send the message to the channel.